# Trouble Routing Traffic between 2 KVM Hosts

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, iptables

I am attempting to create a networked KVM setup as described in the following guide: https://c3rb3ru5d3d53c.github.io/2022/06/kvm-malware-lab/

My network topography is as follows:

```
  ┌────────┐
  │Internet│
  └───┬────┘
      │
┌─────┴──────┐
│Host Machine│ Kernel Virtual Machine (KVM) on DMZ
└─────┬──────┘
      │
    ┌─┴─┐
    │NAT│ (default)
    └─┬─┘
      │
  ┌───┴───┐ ┌────────┐
  │PFSense├─┤Isolated│ LAN 10.0.1.1/24 (vmbr0)
  └───────┘ └───┬────┘
                │
             ┌──┴───┐
             │Remnux│ Static Analysis and Interception
             └──┬───┘
                │
            ┌───┴────┐
            │Isolated│ Analysis LAN 10.0.2.1/24 (vmbr1)
            └─┬──────┤
              │      │
      ┌───────┴───┐ ┌┴──────┐
      │Analysis VM│ │Windows│ Dynamic Analysis
      └───────────┘ └───────┘
```

I am attempting to configure the network so that LAN 10.0.2.1/24 (vmbr1) can only access the internet when LAN 10.0.1.1/24 (vmbr0) is connected to the internet using a VPN. The issue I am having is the Windows machine on LAN 10.0.2.1/24 (vmbr1) is unable to connect to the internet, even when a VPN is enabled.

In attempting to troubleshoot the issue I have discovered the following:

DNS and DHCP are working correctly on LAN vmbr1
The windows machine successfully sends a SYN packet to to 10.0.2.1 but receives no response
Some devices on vmbr0 can ping 10.0.2.1
10.0.1.1 cannot ping 10.0.2.1
From this is have determined the issue is related to a failure in communication between 10.0.2.1 and 10.0.1.1, but I am unsure what is the root cause.

Here is the networking information from my Remnux machine on 10.0.1.1:

My etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml is:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: yes
    enp7s0:
      addresses:
- 10.0.2.1/24
```

My output for `ip route` is:

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.200.0.137 dev tun0 
default via 10.0.1.1 dev enp1s0 proto dhcp src 10.0.1.11 metric 100 
10.0.1.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.11 metric 100 
10.0.1.1 dev enp1s0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.1.11 metric 100 
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp7s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.1 
10.200.0.1 via 10.200.0.137 dev tun0 metric 1 
10.200.0.137 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.200.0.138 
<Redacted VPN IP> via 10.0.1.1 dev enp1s0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.200.0.137 dev tun0 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

My output for `iptables -t nat -L` is:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere            
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I am new to networking, so I am not sure how to troubleshoot my issues. Any help would be appreciated.